# How to forward the request to another JSP page upon click of a link in a JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a link in the jsp page, upon the link click, how can I forward the request to another jsp page.

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to GET a new jsp then simply

```
<a href="/jsp/newJsp.jsp">Click Here</a>
```

**Note:**   the  path to jsp will start from `/` the public web space the same dir  where `WEB-INF` resides

if you mean [`forward`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref11.fm9.html) then

Upon click you will perform GET operation , So lets say

you click

```
<a href="/yourApp/ForwardServlet/">Click Here</a>
```

make a Servlet entry in web.xml and map it to   `/ForwardServlet` to `ForwardServlet` and in Servlet perform

```
public class ForwardServlet extends HttpServlet{

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)             throws ServletException, IOException {


        String destination = "/WEB-INF/pages/result.jsp";

        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(destination);
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

**Refer :**

- [Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: Note that a servlet isn't strictly necessary when the JSP just represents static content in public webcontent (not inside WEB-INF). Just have an `<a href="page.jsp">` then.

Comment: @BalusC OP wants to `forward` a request, ofcourse it can be done directly from jsp but servlet is better idea I guess. also what do you say on hiding jsp in public web space ? I feel this is better if we hide jsps, I would like to know your opinion and thanks

Comment: True, but there's a little ambiguity in the "forward" term the OP used. Don't underestimate the ignorance :) Since the OP asked this pretty trivial question...

Comment: @BalusC :) Ok Updated a bit added info about GET. I hope this makes it better