# How to use request.setAttribute() to set and pass value by clicking on a link

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to pass value of a rowNo from one jsp file to another jsp file(to display image on that row) by using request.setAttribute() and request.getAttribute() whenever user clicks on a link.

But when I try to use request.getAttribute() on second jsp page it gives following exception:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

On Index.jsp page I have :

```
<%!
 int temp = 1;

 %>

<a href="single.jsp" onclick="<%= request.setAttribute("val", temp) %>" > 
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right icon"></i> </a>
```

And on single.jsp page :

```
<%

dbConnect con = new dbConnect(); 
ResultSet r = con.getConnection().executeQuery("select * from tblpic "); 

String tp = (String) (request.getAttribute("val"));

int i = Integer.parseInt(tp);

r.absolute(i);

%>

<div class="thumb-image"> <img src="<%= r.getString(2) %>" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive"> </div>
```

r.absolute(i) is used to move to that specific row in table.

I have added this file on both jsp pages(I don't know it is necessary or not)    <%@page import = "javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest"%>

I am working on net beans and struts framework.

Comment: Kashi let one jsp send data to a servlet. Then forward the data from that servlet to second jsp. Also, writing java is highly discouraged in jsps. Do the logic stuff in servlets and only "show" the data in jsps. No that import statement in not neccassary.

Comment: @FarazDurrani   thanks, can you please give me the example of this in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mixed server side code and client side code together. "request" is a java object and part of servelet request handling. it works at server side only while rendering jsp in servlet  container.

"onclick" is a java script click trigger run at browser side.

Once page get displayed "request" is not logger valid.  and on clicking of submitting new request..new object of request will created.

For you, can easily pass parameter argument to jsp as follow.

on first jsp:

`<a href="single.jsp?val=temp" >`

on second jsp:

`<%=request.getParameter("val")%>`

Comment: I have tried this and came up with this exception : javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot absolute position to row 0

Comment: I know it is because of r.absolute(). I have initialized temp variable above with 1 but this value is not passed and the value received on the other page is 0 or NULL. I even try passing constant but still getting  NULL on the second page.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer `session.setAttribute()` instead of  `request.setAttribute()` to pass value from one jsp to another.

So your code will be:

```
<a href="single.jsp" onclick="<%= session.setAttribute("val", temp) %>" >
```

And

```
String tp = (String) (session.getAttribute("val"));
```

Comment: I wrote this but it is giving following errors:
method setAttribute in interface HttpSession cannot be applied to given types....
Required : string,object
Found : no arguments

Comment: In JSP, session is an implicit object of type HttpSession, so we can use it directly. Have updated my answer.

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 421 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
'void' type not allowed here

Answer (score 1):

You are setting values in request scope. Request scope attributes are only accessible in the same request. Whenever the end user clicks on the link(provided by ), a new request is generated hence you loose the attributes that you set in the previous request.

To Solve the problem you could do

1) URL forwarding as explained by Piyush Aghera

2) You can store the value in the session as explained by PVR

3) If you prefer to store the values in request attribute only, then I would suggest you to use RequestDispatcher to forward your request. This would work as your request on the next page would remain same.

Comment: Can you please give me the example of 3rd point in my case.I have tried 1 and 2 and both doesn't work.

Comment: Your problem got solved but since you asked about the 3rd point, I think you should look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608340/how-to-forward-the-request-to-another-jsp-page-upon-click-of-a-link-in-a-jsp-pag